# Alternative to Outlook with exchange support for enterprise environment

Tags: windows, email-client

I am looking for Outlook alternative that would run under Windows that satisfies the following requirements (in order of importance):

1. Supports Czech language interface.
2. Absolutely no hidden cloud traffic, all data have to be local and stay local, nothing is to be sent to any online servers to do any ai (such as predictive typing) or other type of modern cloud/ai nonsense.
3. No ransom payments (so either free or one time payment).
4. Exchange support (ews).
5. Suitable for deployment via GPO.

So far I have found only Thunderbird that would support 1-5 (at least on "paper" - GPO deployment not tested). But it  has such a clumsy interface that I cannot really force users to go through that horror.

1-4 are supported by eM Client but it's less than mediocre support team with no understanding of active directory environment and the meaning of unattended and the fact that in 2 months of testing I got some 4x times corrupted database, which means setup everything again, is really off-putting.

There are others that I am very tempted by but they do not satisfy the most important requirement - language support.

I am hoping I have missed some amazing solution?